# c++ Virtual ListView in Tile view, can't get subitems to appear

Tags: c++, listview, win32gui

I have a straight win32 c++ app and I'm filling the window with a ListView whose view type is set to LV_VIEW_TILE and I'm also setting the style to LVS_OWNERDATA.

I'm having trouble trying to work out how to get the subitems to show. This code creates the view.

```
DWORD exstyle =WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE|LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER|LVS_EX_JUSTIFYCOLUMNS|LVS_EX_INFOTIP;

g_hwndList = CreateWindowEx(exstyle, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_ICON | LVS_OWNERDATA, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU) 2702, hInst, NULL);

ListView_SetView(g_hwndList, LV_VIEW_TILE);
LVTILEVIEWINFO tileViewInfo = { };
tileViewInfo.cbSize = sizeof(LVTILEVIEWINFO);
tileViewInfo.dwFlags = LVTVIF_AUTOSIZE;
tileViewInfo.dwMask = LVTVIM_COLUMNS;
tileViewInfo.cLines = 1;

BOOL tst = ListView_SetTileViewInfo(g_hwndList, &tileViewInfo);
```

I only want one more subitem/column to appear. In my LVN_GETDISPINFO I currently have this:

```
static int colfmt[1];
colfmt[0] = LVCFMT_LEFT;

static int order[1];
order[0] = 1;

if ((nimfo->item.mask & LVIF_COLUMNS) == LVIF_COLUMNS) {
    nimfo->item.cColumns = 1;
    nimfo->item.piColFmt = PINT(colfmt);
    nimfo->item.puColumns = PUINT(order);
}

if ((nimfo->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT) == LVIF_TEXT) {
    nimfo->item.pszText = di->LABEL;
}

if ((nimfo->item.mask & LVIF_IMAGE) == LVIF_IMAGE) {
    nimfo->item.iImage = di->IMAGE_INDEX;
}
```

I can't work out at what point and where I need to supply the subitem/column text, I'm never seeing the nimfo->item.subitem changing from 0 and for each call for LVIF_TEXT the structure values are always the same.

So at what point do I need to supply the extra textual data?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I, rather stupidly, wasn't adding any columns and therefore wasn't being asked for the other items.

added this and everything works

```
LVCOLUMN col = {};
col.mask = LVCF_SUBITEM;
col.iSubItem = 0;
ListView_InsertColumn(g_hwndList, 0, &col);
```

Comment: +1. Just had the same problem (but in Delphi). Since columns aren't visible by default in tile view, this is not entirely obvious.